# New to unix need help with script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am working on a script but I keep getting this error  Syntax error: ")" unexpected (expecting ";;")

here's the script

```
#!/bin/sh
#Name:gamer
#Date Created: 12/6/2015
#last modified: 12/8/2015
#Desc/Purpose: Updating and installing apps.
DATE=$(date -d "$1" +"%m_%d_%Y");
condition=y
while [ $condition = "y" ] || [ $condition = "Y" ]
do

clear

echo -n "Do you know how to Update OS"
read answer

if [ $answer = "y" ] || [ $answer = "Y" ]; then
    echo "Good update the os then."

elif [ $answer = "n" ]; then
    echo "would you like me to update it for you"
    read response
    if  [ $response = "y" ]; then
        echo "updating os!"
            sudo apt-get update os
clear
echo -n "which app would you like to install"
read answer

if [ $answer = "y" ] || [ $answer = "Y" ]; then
        echo "A) Install Webmin"
        echo "B) Install Apache"
        echo "C) Install gnome shell"
        echo "D) get ubuntu desktop"
        echo "E) Add new user"
        echo "F) get Xubuntu Desktop"
        echo "G) Install openbox"
        echo "H) remove Libre office"
        echo "I) I don't want to install anything"
        read option

        case $option in 
            A) sudo apt-get install webmin ;;
            B) sudo apt-get install apache ;;
            C) sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ;;
            D) sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop ;;
            E) sudo useradd ;;
            F) sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop ;;
            G) sudo apt-get install openbox ;;
            H) sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice* ;;
            I) echo "You can always do it later"
            *) echo "Please select one of the options"


done
```

All help is appreciated it thankyou.

Comment: You are missing a `;;` after case `I)`, and also some `fi`s for your `if`s: you may want to take a look at http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 2):

The correct one:

```
#!/bin/sh
#Name:gamer
#Date Created: 12/6/2015
#last modified: 12/8/2015
#Desc/Purpose: Updating and installing apps.
DATE=$(date -d "$1" +"%m_%d_%Y");
condition=y
while [ $condition = "y" ] || [ $condition = "Y" ]
do

clear

echo -n "Do you know how to Update OS"
read answer

if [ $answer = "y" ] || [ $answer = "Y" ]; then
    echo "Good update the os then."

elif [ $answer = "n" ]; then
    echo "would you like me to update it for you"
    read response
    if  [ $response = "y" ]; then
        echo "updating os!"
            sudo apt-get update os
    fi
fi
clear
echo -n "which app would you like to install"
read answer

if [ $answer = "y" ] || [ $answer = "Y" ]; then
        echo "A) Install Webmin"
        echo "B) Install Apache"
        echo "C) Install gnome shell"
        echo "D) get ubuntu desktop"
        echo "E) Add new user"
        echo "F) get Xubuntu Desktop"
        echo "G) Install openbox"
        echo "H) remove Libre office"
        echo "I) I don't want to install anything"
        read option

        case $option in 
            A) sudo apt-get install webmin ;;
            B) sudo apt-get install apache ;;
            C) sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ;;
            D) sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop ;;
            E) sudo useradd ;;
            F) sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop ;;
            G) sudo apt-get install openbox ;;
            H) sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice* ;;
            I) echo "You can always do it later" ;;
            *) echo "Please select one of the options" ;;
        sac
fi
done
```

Comment: Suggestion:  add `sleep 3` before the clear statement, because screen is cleared , and user never really sees `echo "Good update the os then."` part

Comment: Yes, that's great suggestion. I've just fixed the syntax errors of @Gamer only.

Comment: @Gamer if possible please mark my answer as "Accepted"